# Drupal 7 - Display Content type as Block and Block Naming Convention

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I created a content type which has some fields and i want this fields to only be displayed as block. I tried to renaming a block in my 'theme/template' as block--[machine-name].tpl.php but is of now use.

And

How to name a block which is generated from a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your views page, click edit on the view you want to theme.

Open up the advanced options and click on `Theme: information`.

This should bring up the following popup that explains **exactly** what to name your template.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To the second question "How to name a block which is generated from a view."

from Drupal 7 official documentation here: [Theming Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/theming-blocks)

`block--[module]--[delta].tpl.php`

so your views block tpl would be:

```
block--views--views-machine-name-display-name.tpl.php
```

Also same question asked here:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/create-template-file-for-views-block

Comment: Please add this as a seperate question, I'm more than happy to answer it for you. Per the rules of stack overflow you should not be asking a seperate question on someone else's question especially in the form of an answer. Please comment here with a link to your question and i'll help answer it for you.

Comment: Shawn it was an answer, to the question above. lol 
I felt like the accepted answer wasn't complete. That's it.

Comment: Ahh my mistake.

Comment: Sorry about that!